# QMYSQL driver not loaded on Mac OS for Mac M1/M2 users

Tags: c++, qt, apple-m1, mysql-connector

When I run following code:

```cpp
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("SecureChat");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("zTmUHsbEKZZlWhfofM");
    bool ok = db.open();

    qDebug() << db.lastError();
```

I receive error:
`QT/C++ QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded on OSx`

How to fix it on Mac m1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original solution I have [found here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/136231/mysql-plugin-on-m1-mac/10) thanks to the original author of the question and answer - `chriam.`

I will describe in this post some key points that are not mentioned in the original solution.

1. You have to install [MySQL from Oracle cloud](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/c-api/)
2. Use `QT  maintenanceTool` and choose the option `Add or remove components.` From the list, choose your current QT version and put a mark on `Sources`, then click next and wait for files to download.
3. Follow insctruction [here to](https://macappstore.org/ninja/) install `ninja`
4. `cd` to your Src folder in my case: `cd /Users/lamens/Qt/6.3.2/Src`
5. Run the following command and wait for its complitaion `./configure -sql-mysql -- -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib"`
6. `cd` to your sqldrivers folder in my case: `cd /Users/lamens/Qt/6.3.2/macos/plugins/sqldrivers`
7. Run `mkdir build_sqldrivers` and then `cd build_sqldrivers`
8. Run command: `/Users/<user>/Qt/<qt_version>/macos/bin/qt-cmake -G Ninja /Users/<user>/Qt/<qt_version>/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/<user>/Qt/<qt_version>/macos -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/local/mysql/include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib" -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="arm64`
   Where `<user>` is your system user and `<qt_version>` is your QT version :D.
9. `sed -i -e 's/-arch x86_64/-arch arm64/g' /Users/<user>/Qt/<qt_version>/macos/plugins/sqldrivers/build_sqldrivers/build.ninja` if this fails, change at the  `build.ninja` (it is at the `build_sqldrivers` folder) file all occurrences of `arch x86_64` to the `arch arm64`.
10. Run at the `build_sqldrivers` folder `cmake --build .`
11. Run at the `build_sqldrivers` folder `cmake --install .`
12. Then locate your lib using: `find ~/Qt -name libqsqlmysql.dylib` and move newly generated `libqsqlmysql.dylib` to the `/Users/<user>/Qt/<qt_version>/macos/plugins/sqldrivers` folder.
13. Voilaa!